# Prove $\frac{n^2+1}{n+1}$ is $\mathcal{O}(n)$

Tags: asymptotics

I'm trying to proving this formula $\frac{n^2+1}{n+1}$ is $\mathcal{O}(n)$.

As you know we need to come up with $n_0$ and $C$. So I'm confusing a little bit in how to choose a appropriate $C$ since the equation here is division.

For $n > 1$, $n^2+1<n^2+n < n(n+1)$, so $\frac{n^2+1}{n+1} < n$ , for n > 1.

So we proved that for $C = 1, n_0=1:~\frac{n^2+1}{n+1} \leq Cn$ ; ($C=1$)

but I'm stuck here in how to simplest the fraction here.

Comment: Wait, so you've already shown that $\frac{n^{2}+1}{n+1} \leq n$ for all $n\geq 1?$ Does this not fit your definition of $\frac{n^{2}+1}{n+1} = O(n)$ as $n\to\infty,$ with $n_{0}=1$ and $C=1?$ What is left to show?

Comment: You see, the two answers you received so far are *more complicated* than yours -- so indeed, what are you asking?

Answer (score 3):

If $n \geq n_0 = 1$, then:
$$
\frac{n^2 + 1}{n + 1} \leq \frac{n^2 + n}{n + 1} = \frac{n(n + 1)}{n + 1} = n = Cn
$$
and so we're done.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{n^2+1}{n+1}=\frac{(n+1)(n-1)+2}{n+1}=n-1+\frac2{n+1}=O(n)+O(1)+O\left(\frac1n\right)=O(n)$$

Comment: did you use C=1 ?

Comment: I used a combination of the definition of big-O notation ($O(f(n))=g(n)$ as $n\to\infty$ means that ...) and the fact that knowing that definition and a few simple rules coming from it (e.g $kn=O(n)$ or $O(n^a)+O(n^b)=O(n^{\max(a,b)}$) that allow one to solve this type of problem quickly and intuitively

Answer (score 0):

Use polynomial division. You should get a polynomial plus a rational function.

Comment: How I get polynomial division?

Comment: What Dan Robinson did was polynomial division. Here is the relevant link.https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_long_division

Answer (score 0):

To prove $\mathcal{O}(n)$, you need to prove it from both above and below.

Which you (almost) did. If we add an $n^2-1$ argument on the LHS: $$n^2-1\lt n^2+1\le n^2+n = n(n+1)$$

so we have $$\frac{n^2-1}{n+1} \lt \frac{n^2+1}{n+1}\le n$$

$$n-1 \lt \frac{n^2+1}{n+1}\le n$$

and we are done.